# Meu formulário não envia Cópia do e-mail

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário que envia os dados para o administrador, mas não envia a cópia para o e-mail do cliente.

Segue o código:

```
$to = $email;
$emailoculto = $email;
$subject = "Seu pedido ao restaurante BARDANA - Número do Pedido: 00" .$gerador;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$headers .= "From: \"{$nome}\" <ramos@empresa.com.br>\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: <ramos@empresa.com.br>\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: {$emailoculto}\r\n";

//mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
```

Encontrei aqui essa ideia de colocar o `Bcc` dessa forma, mas mesmo assim não vai a cópia. No e-mail ramos@empresa.com.br eu recebo normalmente, e ainda aparece cópia para o e-mail do cliente, mas de fato ele não envia essa cópia.

Comment: Testou com `Bcc: <$emailoculto>\r\n"`? seria o correto. Tão faltando os `< >` no seu Bcc. Por outro lado, os `{ }` são desnecessários.

Comment: PS: Pra poucos volumes eu sugiro usar o mail duas vezes em vez de bcc, até pra evitar "vazamento" de headers em implementações bugadas (já soube de caso de certos mailers que não apagam o header do Bcc da ,mensagem original por engano);

Comment: Está misturando o html com php na linha 

'$headers .= "Bcc: {$emailoculto}\r\n" '

Fecha tudo direito e veja se funciona.

Comment: Estranho, realmente não funcionou com "Bcc: <$emailoculto>\r\n";

Comment: Não entendi o que seria fechar tudo?